# Why doesn't modal work with PHP for show A few words

Tags: php, html

I have a table. Inside the table is the name of the book. Now I want to show the user what is in the table and when the user clicks on the word showIFRAME2, the name of the book is moved to the modal and show modal. But the problem is that if the name of the book It consists of two words, The modal does not work. For example, if the name of the book is  (Hello Nature), the modal does not work, but if the name of the book
(Hello_ Nature) the modal work.

If you look at the code, the modal does not work to pass the variable $mm2, but the modal work to pass the variable `$mm`

```
$mm="you";
$mm2="how are you";
 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr class="$page">';
    echo '<td class="text-center">' . $i . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['book_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['book_writer'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['book_unit'] . '</td>';      
    echo '<td class="text-center">' . $row['book_category'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td class="center">
            <a data-toggle="modal" class="delete"  data-target="#myModal" 
                href="iframe.php?id=80&ss=' . $mm . '&ss2=' . $mm2 . '&mydiv=125&book_name=' . $row["book_name"] .'">
                <h1>showIFRAME2<h1>
            </a>
        </td>';
    
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Encode your SPACE with %20 ? https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Where's the code that moves something to that modal?

Comment: urlencode the info in the href first

Comment: when i  clicks on the word showIFRAME2 ,The modal does not work Because a variable($mm2) consists of several words(how are you).If I change the value of the variable, for example, as follows(howareyou),modal works.                                 <a data-toggle="modal" class="delete"  data-target="#myModal" 
                href="iframe.php?id=80&ss=' . $mm . '&ss2=' . $mm2 . '&mydiv=125&book_name=' . $row["book_name"] .'">
                <h1>showIFRAME2<h1>
            </a>

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. How does the generated markup look like? What does "does not work" mean? Are you facing any error message, either in your JS console or on the network tab?